# serialize java objects of different classes into a single row in CSV using JSEFA

Tags: java, csv, serialization

I am using JSEFA to serialize my java object to into single row in CSV using JSEFA.
I have arround 46 fields in one single class ,

But now the problem is i want to split this class into different sub classes which holds information,One class contains fields of CSV for first 23 positions and next class contains remaining position. When i tried approach of Prefix it is inserting data into two different rows but i need all data of two classes into a single row 
can some body suggest best approach using JSEFA or any other .

First class contains first two fields:

```
@CsvDataType(defaultPrefix = "1")

public class TestClass1 implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 371968159365574089L;

@CsvField(pos = 1)
private int id;

@CsvField(pos = 2)
private String Name;

public int getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(final int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return this.Name;
}

public void setName(final String name) {
    this.Name = name;
}
  }
```

Sub Class 2 which contains remaining two fields:

```
@CsvDataType(defaultPrefix = "2")
 public class TestClass2 implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 371968159365574089L;

@CsvField(pos = 3)
private int orderno;

@CsvField(pos = 4)
private String orderName;

public int getOrderno() {
    return this.orderno;
}

public void setOrderno(final int orderno) {
    this.orderno = orderno;
}


public String getOrderName() {
    return orderName;
}


public void setOrderName(String orderName) {
    this.orderName = orderName;
}


  }
```

main method for combining:

```
 public static void main(final String[] args) {

final File file = new File("/home/chandra/Documents/dataExcelFiles/final.csv");
    file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
 Serializer serializer = CsvIOFactory.createFactory(TestClass.class,  TestClass2.class).createSerializer();

    TestClass prod1 = new TestClass();

    prod1.setId(1);
    prod1.setName("HTC");

    TestClass2 prod2 = new TestClass2();
    prod2.setOrderno(512);
    prod2.setOrderName("HTC500");

    try {

        serializer.open(new FileWriter(file));
        serializer.write(prod1);
        serializer.write(prod2);
        serializer.close(true);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Using this approach out put is like this :

- 1 1      HTC
- 2 512 HTC500

but i need out put every thing in one row  like this:

- 1      HTC      512   HTC500

Thanks,
Chandra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

serializer.write method will write one record. Since you use it twice with (different arguments of jsefa classes), it writes 2 records

What you need is something like this:

Sub Class 1:

```
@Embeddable
@CsvDataType
public class TestClass1 implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 371968159365574089L;

@CsvField(pos = 1)
private int id;

@CsvField(pos = 2)
private String Name;

// getter setter methods
}
```

Sub Class 2:

```
@Embeddable
@CsvDataType
public class TestClass2 implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 371968159365574089L;

@CsvField(pos = 3)
private int orderno;

@CsvField(pos = 4)
private String orderName;

// getter setter methods
}
```

Parent Class:

```
@CsvDataType()
public class TestClass {
    @CsvField ( pos = 1)
    private TestClass1 testClass1;
    @CsvField ( pos = 2)
    private TestClass2 testClass2;

    // getter setter methods
}
```

Your main method:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {

final File file = new File("/home/chandra/Documents/dataExcelFiles/final.csv");
    file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
 Serializer serializer = CsvIOFactory.createFactory(TestClass.class,  TestClass2.class).createSerializer();

    TestClass testClass = new TestClass();

    testClass.getTestClass1().setId(1);
    testClass.getTestClass1().setName("HTC");
    testClass.getTestClass2().setOrderno(512);
    testClass.getTestClass2().setOrderName("HTC500");

    try {

        serializer.open(new FileWriter(file));
        serializer.write(testClass);
        serializer.close(true);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

If you want to use Default Prefix, you can add DefaultPrefix as '1' in TestClass and remove 'id' from TestClass1. That means, all records will start with '1'